# how to add multiple images to the django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am new to the django. I am trying to add multiple images to the django template like blog post. I am not getting how to do it. please help me.

I am not getting how to save the image in single image field
and how to upload multiple image

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=244, null=True)
    shop_address = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    abn = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    Emg_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True,blank=True)
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    area_code = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=2)
    landline_number =  models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=9)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, blank=True, null=True)
    user_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_image')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'registration_userprofile'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create another Image model and give it Foreignkey Relationship in your User model.Something like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    *image related fields*

class User(models.Model):
    *user fields*        
    image = models.Foreignkey(Image)
```

Do read about django many-to-many fields and one-to-one fields.[Django Model relationship document.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/)

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume you want to have a couple of pictures related to one Userprofile and let a user upload more than one pictures in your view at once. In your models.py you add:

```
class Image(models.Model):
   user = models.Foreignkey(UserProfile)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images')
```

In your template you do:

```
<form action="/pic_upload/{{request.user.id}}/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Select Pictures: </td><td><input name="files" type="file" size="50" accept="image/*" multiple>  </td>
        <td><button type="submit"> Upload </button> </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

(Note that the table structure I have used above is just an example.)

Then you need to create the view that saves the images, so in your views.py add:

```
  from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
  from django.shortcuts import redirect


  @login_required
  def pic_upload(request,user_id):
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(user__id=user_id)
        for afile in request.FILES.getlist('files'):
            pic = Picture()
            pic.user= user 
            pic.image = afile
            pic.save()

        return redirect("path_to_where_you_want_to_go_after_upload")
```

This is just the view for the image upload - you also need one that shows your template.

(Note that this only works if a user is logged in and the request context processor is activated. If you do not need to login the user you can e.g.  make a select box for the user and add the logic.)

Then you need to hook those things up in the urls.py:

```
url(r'^pic_upload/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', pic_upload, name='pic_upload'),
```